# I am trying to get battery power status of my laptop using python, but facing problem with getting the live updated battery status value

Tags: python, battery, psutil

So I am trying to get live update of the battery power status, that is if the laptop is plugged in and charging or if it is running on battery power.
I am using **psutil** library in python to retrieve the required data but the data I am getting back is limited to one time retrieval that is it is not updating while the program run.

```
import psutil
import keyboard

battery = psutil.sensors_battery()

print("Starting Program...")

while True:
    status = battery.power_plugged
    print(status)
    if keyboard.is_pressed("q"):
        break
    elif(status == True):
        print("Charging...")
    elif(status == False):
        print("Discharging...")

print("Closing Program...")
```

Here I am either getting only "true" and "Charging..." or "false" and "Discharging..." irrespective of the change in status. So how can I get around this, any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get updated status in the `while` as follows:

```
import psutil
import keyboard
import time

print("Starting Program...")

while True:
    battery = psutil.sensors_battery()
    status = battery.power_plugged
    print(status)
    if keyboard.is_pressed("q"):
        break
    elif(status == True):
        print("Charging...")
    elif(status == False):
        print("Discharging...")
    time.sleep(1)
print("Closing Program...")
```

Comment: Awesome @BhaweshVerma, please consider accepting the answer to mark the question as resolved.

Comment: Sure I will, I have to wait about 10 minutes before I could accept the answer. Thanks again.